# Prisma Throwing a Typeerror After Deployment to Vercel, Problem Narrowed to Extending Prisma Generated Types

Tags: typescript, prisma, vercel

After deploying my app to Vercel I get a 500 error when navigating to some pages with this output:

> TypeError: The specifier “.prisma/client/index-browser” was a bare
> specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module
> specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”

I've narrowed the problem down to using these lines to create types using subsets of properties of the generated types that Prisma created based on my schema.

```
const studentFull = Prisma.validator<Prisma.StudentDefaultArgs>() ({
    include: { 
        openPeriods:true,
        sessionRecords:true,
        assignedDays:true,
    }
})

type StudentFull = Prisma.StudentGetPayload<typeof studentFull>
```

When you comment out this code and get rid of the typing based on it the page works beautifully, but obviously Typescript argues with me about the typing.

Is there any way to make this work with correct typing? I'd like to get it done correctly using TypeScript.

Comment: This is better being posted on the Prisma GitHub repo
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues